# pymssql.operational Error

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, sql-server-2008, pymssql

I am using python and pymssql for SQL connection.
Basically i am fetching some data from 'table1' and doing some
Mathematical calculation and inserting into 'table2'
I have tested my python script with limited number of
records from 'table1' and it was working fine.
Then I have started my script with real time data,ie really huge
amount of data(122457 records)
Then I have faced given below issue

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trakryt_main_mod.py", line 312, in <module>
    create_visitwalkby_table()
  File "trakryt_main_mod.py", line 126, in create_visitwalkby_table
    scenarios.one_beacon(cursor,orgid)
  File "C:\Nikhil\trak_reporting\python\scenarios.py", line 260, in one_beacon
    close_visit()
  File "C:\Nikhil\trak_reporting\python\scenarios.py", line 207, in close_visit
    conn = pymssql.connect(server,user,password,db,port=port)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 645, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10301)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 247, in pymssql.Connection.__init__ (pymssql.c:3771)
pymssql.OperationalError: Cannot start transaction: (20004, 'DB-Lib error messag
e 20004, severity 9:\nRead from the server failed\nNet-Lib error during Unknown
error (10054)\n')
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the same server that you had successfully used for your initial testing?

Comment: Yes,using same server